# Courier font just not working

Tags: fonts

(Latex, Mac OS X)

Imagine we want use courier font.
Start from this:

```
\texttt{Wanna nice monospace font here}
{\ttfamily TeleType And here}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontfamily=courier]
    And here please too!
\end{Verbatim}
```

This is not working. First two sections (texttt and ttfamily) have monospace font, but from stone age. In 2015 that's not good.
Last section (begin/end Verbatim) doesn't work completely - it prints totally non-monospace font which looks like times-new-roman which is rather far from monospace (especially courier).

I've tried

```
\usepackage{courier}
```

And even

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Why user should care about it in 2015 btw?
                         % T2A not working too.
```

So this package makes "times-new-roman-like" font instead of any monospace font. Well, maybe useless package?

As I know, many latex packages are incompatible with each other. I've tried to investigate it, but no success.

Here is the header of latex document:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

** So the main question is: How to get nice monospace font Courier in latex? **

** Edit: Of course I need Courier in verbatim environmend AND with russian letters. As I see, latex is rather ancient to deal with it.
Could be there alternative solutions? Like:
1) Another nice monospace font like Courier, but better than standard stone-age font.
2) Another latex engine? xetex, xelatex? can they deal with it?
**

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's no Cyrillic support with Courier. If your verbatim parts don't use Cyrillic, something can be done, of course.

Answer (score 3):

If your verbatim text doesn't contain Cyrillic letters, you can modify the setup macro of `fancyvrb` to use the T1 encoding. The problem is that TeX distributions don't feature a Cyrillic Courier compatible font.

Similarly, you can use a similar declaration for `listings`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\FV@SetupFont}
  {\FV@BaseLineStretch}
  {\fontencoding{T1}\FV@BaseLineStretch}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible
}

\begin{document}

Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.

\begin{Verbatim}
some verbatim text in Courier
\end{Verbatim}

Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.

\begin{lstlisting}
some verbatim text in Courier
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A monospaced font that has coverage for Cyrillic is PTMono; unfortunately, `listings` does not behave well with UTF-8 characters (check with `listings-utf8` that however requires using `\lstinputlisting`).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage[scaled=0.9]{PTMono}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.

\begin{Verbatim}
some дословно text in PTMono
\end{Verbatim}

Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you're keen to switch to XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, then there's no big problem, if you have an OpenType/TrueType version of Courier on your system that supports Cyrillic; in my case it's called Courier New.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O} % or whatever
\setmonofont[Scale=MatchLowercase]{Courier New}

\begin{document}

Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.

\begin{Verbatim}
some дословно text in Courier
\end{Verbatim}

Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.
Этот текст на русском языке.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same as above can be said about `lstlisting`. You may also want to look at `minted`.